# Travel between Managua and Monteverde

Tags: public-transport, buses, backpacking, costa-rica, nicaragua

What's the best way to get between Managua and Monteverde.  I am trying to keep it as cheap  as possible without having to switch buses 10 times between.  Is there a simple way to do it? Am I better off just booking through a large international bus company?

Answer (score 1):

[Rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Managua/Monteverde) says bus via Puntarenas, for a total cost between 24-35`EUR`. The international bus company is [Transnica](http://transnica.com/). The second segment is a local bus N. 675. For completeness sake note that [Transnica has some not-so-positive feedback on tripadvisor dating 2013](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g291982-i813-k6145103-Beware_TransNica_their_bus_didn_t_stop_for_us-Costa_Rica.html). I don't know if the situation has changed since then, but it might be worth asking around in Nicaragua.

There's another, more expensive option with 4 different buses, but why would you want to do that to yourself.

Note that Rome2rio prices might not be up-to-date and must therefore be double checked on site.

An even cheaper option could be hitchiking, of course.